# My laravel website is working fine on hosted but on local server its showing "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My website is in **laravel** 5.5
The website is working fine on the hosted server and was working on local also but not now. the error message is "**The page has expired due to inactivity.  Please refresh and try again.**".

I already have placed  **{{ csrf_field() }}** Now you can see whole code of blade template.

```
<div class="registration_form_area">                    
    <form class="registration_form" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
         <div class="row">                   
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">E-mail Address</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <div class="group">
            <input type="text" required name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                                    <span class="bar"></span>
                                    <label>E-mail Address</label>
                                </div>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="error_text">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <div class="group">
                                    <input type="password" required name="password" id="password">
                                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                                    <span class="bar"></span>
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                </div>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="error_text">{{ $errors->first('password') }} </span>
                                 @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="color: #CF6988; font-size: 16px;">
                    <div style="float: left;">    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }} >  Remember Me</div>

                    <div style="float: right;"><a class="btn btn-link"  href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <!--<img src="images/captcha.jpg" class="img-responsive">-->
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-xs-12 cols-sm-6 cols-md-4">
                        <div class="submit_area">
                        <button class="submit_button" type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
                        </div></div>

                    </div></form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: did u cleared all cache files use `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: command php artisan optimize:clear does not exist. Please tell write correct command.

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/clear-cache-laravel-5/

Comment: change file permission writable important storage folder

Answer (score 0):

First, Try to clear all your cache using:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

```
php artisan route:clear
```

```
php artisan view:clear
```

If the issue still not fixed, You may have set your environment to work on https on server while it's on http on your localhost. Check your `config/session.php`.

Comment: in app.php file i am using http on both( local & hosted server)  .'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'), and   'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 35791394), in session.php

Comment: You may be using a form without {{ csrf_field() }}.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `.env` file is not being read due caching.
Try below commands in your cmd.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Also clear cache in Laravel(browser)

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

Write above route in `web.php` and access that route. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have executed all the artisan command, and paste code in web.php but nothing is working.